# how to solve a jquery ajax issue?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

i have a simple ajax post and something is going wrong. here is my code:

```
<div id="one_hundredContent"></div>
<a href="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="id"></a>
<a href="100" id="one_hundred"><div class="tab6_stats_under1">100</div></a>
```

and js

```
$('#one_hundred').live("click", function() {
var votes = $("#one_hundred").attr("href");
var id = $("#id").attr("href");
var dataString = 'id=' + id+ '&votes=' + votes;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://test.com/fileupload.php", 
    dataType: dataString ,
    success: function() {
        $('#one_hundredContent').html('success');
        }
});
return false;
});
```

and php

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['votes'])){
$tal = $_POST['id'];
$votes = $_POST['votes'];

echo $tal.' '. $votes;
die;
}
```

the request goes on OK:

```
Request URL:https://test.com/fileupload.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

but there is no response data, i don't see my variables being passed on or my success message

any idea on what am i missing?

thanks

Comment: have you tried firebuggin it and setting your console to view xml requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dataType: dataString` to `data: dataString`

`dataType` is optional, but if set should be either `xml`, `json`, `script` or `html`